# ¿Como puedo pasar un parámetro de un función a una variable fuera de la función?

Tags: javascript, ajax

lo que quiero saber es como puedo obtener una variable que esta dentro de una función y dentro de esa funcion esta ajax y de ajax quiero obtener la variable que devuelve y pasar ese valor a una variable que se llama slider_id que esta fuera de la función este es el codigo

```
 $('.slideshow').mouseenter(function slan(e) {
        var id = $(this).attr('slider');
        var slin = $(this).attr('id'); 
        
        var action = 'Imagenes';
       
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php',
            type: 'POST',
            async:true,
            data: {action:action,id:id},

            success: function slider(response) {
     
                //console.log(response);

                if (response != 'error') {

                    var info = JSON.parse(response);

                    console.log(info);

                    var slider_id = info.id; esta es el valor que quiero pasar a la variable que esta fuera de la funcion
                     
                    console.log(slider_id); 
                    
                    return slider_id;

                         
                }
                
            },

            error: function(error) {

                console.log(error);
            },
            
        });            

 }); 
    
    var slider_id = 3; //aqui es donde quiero poner el valor que saco de ajax
   
    alert(slider_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Si tu variable slider_id es global, la asignacion que haces en function slider ya deberia bastar. El cambio recomendado es usar slider_id global y no redeclarar en la funcion slider.